# ipad app using splitview controller

Tags: objective-c, ipad

Iam doing an ipad app using splitview controller.Iam getting images from webservice by using custom tableview in rootview.But one problem is when loading the images suddenly struck the simulator. so, What i have to do?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you aren't fetching the images asynchronously, although it is a bit of a wild guess as the question could do with re-phrasing.

IF that is the issue ...

If you are using the SYNCHRONOUS method NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error: you need to wrap it in a NSOperation so it doesn't block the main UI thread.

More usually you would use the asynchronous methods of NSURLConnection.

Better still, consider the third party library [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) which can do all this for you and more.